# Java - printing ArrayList into a text file

Tags: java, file, arraylist, io, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to print my `ArrayList` into my text file, line by line.

```
for (int s = 0; s < list.size(); s++) {
    wr.write(list.get(s));
}
```

or

```
for (String text : list) {
    wr.write(text);
}
```

How am I doing that?
I think the problem is "BufferedWriter" writing the file over and over instead doing new lines. 
What should I do?

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Have you opened the file in `write (w)` mode? If yes, it should be in `append (a)` mode.

Comment: Not writting anything

Comment: please, post some more code (about the initialization of your buffered writer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following function to write line by line -

```
public static void writeLineByLine(){

    try{
      File fout = new File("out.txt");
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);

      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

      for (String text : list) {
        bw.write(text);
        bw.newLine();
      }

    }catch (IOException  e){
      // handle exceptioin        
    }finally{
     bw.close();
    }
}
```

Hope it will help.
Thanks a lot